How to store row data failure when using DBT test?
only the status is stored I tried to use the command --store-failures" and added store_failures: true on schema.yml but it only stored the status instead of all the column data.
I tried to use the command --store-failures" and added store_failures: true on schema.yml.
The expected result is store all column that available in table not only the status
